# Submit unresponsive after ajax call + fadeIn()

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

Good day, fellow programmers.

There's this **index.php** that does an Ajax call to **login.php** and appends the DOM elements and some javascript from inside this into the body of the index. This login.php consists out of a a single **div** that contains a **form** and a **submit** button, which fadeIn() as soon as it is all appended.

However: the submit button is unresponsive!

I did find, after a while, that this does not happen when you **directly** access login.php via URL (.../.../login.php) instead. This means it's the fact that the index appends the whole, which makes them unresponsive.

(Also: in light of this, I've added a $(document).ready(function(){ ... }); around the entire script in the login.php, but that did not seem to help at all. Instead it caused all functions to return errors...)

I'm out of ideas. Perhaps some of you might have had any experience with these matters?

As always, thank you for the time!

Here's the (simplified) code:

**index.php**

```
$('#logInButton').click(function(){
    loadContent('/login/login.php', 'body');
});
```

**loadContent();**

```
function loadContent(url, appendDiv, optionalData, cb) {
    if (appendDiv == '#contentCenter') {
        // vanity code
    }
    if (cb) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            data: optionalData,
            success: function(html){
                $(appendDiv).append(html);
            },
            complete: function(){
                cb();
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            data: optionalData,
            success: function(html){
                $(appendDiv).append(html);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**login.php** (deleted some styling. If you want some specific info, just ask!)

```
<style>
    // some styling
</style>

<div id="loginBlack">
        <div class="login" style="z-index:9999;">
                <form id="myform1" name="myform1">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/inputEmail.png" /> 
                        <div id="emailOverlay">
                            <input id="email" type="text"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input id="iets" name="iets" type="submit"/>
                </form>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // $(document).ready(function(){   // <-- been trying this out.
        $('#loginBlack').fadeIn(t)
        // some functions pertaining to logging in and registering
    // });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of click()

```
$('body').on('click', '#logInButton' ,function(){
    loadContent('/login/login.php', 'body');
});
```

That should make the elements behave properly

Note: you can also replace body selector with something nearer to the click button ( its nearest parent )

**EDIT::**

With this you can have the styling in your normal css file. Put it outside of the login.php

And your js goes into into the success handlers. So just leave the php with the actual html

```
function loadContent(url, appendDiv, optionalData, cb) {
if (appendDiv == '#contentCenter') {
    // vanity code
}
if (cb) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: optionalData,
        success: function(html){
            $(html).hide().appendTo(appendDiv).fadeIn('slow');
        },
        complete: function(){
            cb();
        }
    });
}
else {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: optionalData,
        success: function(html){
            $(html).hide().appendTo(appendDiv).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: made both changes, still not working properly. Every function that I declared in login.php is now 'not defined', according to chrome.

Comment: @Victor Please see my updates. login.php just should just contain the div, styling to ur normal css file and the js into the success function